# Square Web API for Android Kills App

Tags: android, square-connect

I am unable to make a successful connection with the square reader via android request after following documentation found at https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android

It seems straightforward, but the connection links end up crashing the app or causing it to restart without any error reporting or callback information sent to either `S.browser_fallback_url` or `S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI`.

Sample link activated on dev server (127.0.0.1) is: `intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=http://localhost:8080/tb/square;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=http://localhost:8080/tb/square;S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=secret;S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=150;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_OTHER;S.com.squareup.pos.REQUEST_METADATA=5a982466e7b46;S.com.squareup.pos.NOTE=This will be a note!;end`

For the `CLIENT_ID` I was instructed to use Application ID found at https://connect.squareup.com/apps/

Firmware on Contactless, Chip reader is 2.9.36 which is connected to the android device via bluetooth.

--edit--
First time through
https://ibb.co/kSBUYH
https://ibb.co/fyUGDH
Second time through
https://ibb.co/duFZ0x
https://ibb.co/i1MUYH

Comment: Whoa! that isn't good! Could record a video of this behavior?

Comment: @tristansokol images added. video would have been boring (:

Comment: I just wanted to confirm a few things, is your POS App fully setup on the device? Also, I wanted to confirm if you are _actually_ using `localhost` as your callback URL or if you're using the `192.168.88.41`? Finally, are you testing in incognito? I just want to be sure you're not trying to use a cached page with an outdated URL.

Comment: @mootrichard actually using the IP for callback. Not in incognito. The testing is not a complete POS, just the square functionality. The print out of the number at the top of the page is to ensure it is not a cached page.

Comment: "`The testing is not a complete POS`" do you mean that the POS app hasn't been setup yet? [You should set it up if it hasn't been yet.](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android#initiating-a-payment)

Comment: @mootrichard All the POS setup on the android and hardware pairing have been completed. I am logged in to the appropriate account.

Comment: Are you serving your app via SSL? Really puzzled here why it wouldn't be working for you. I took your URL and modified it to just have my own callback url and have that in the dashboard, and I can get it to load the $1.50 charge

Comment: I moved it to prod for a test on SSL and get the same result.

Maybe we could email, SO is kind of slow. I could set up a test on my server you could use. I have sent a few crash reports though your app you can find my email address there.

Comment: [Join our Slack community](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfAZGIEZoNs-XryKqUoW3atFQHdQw5UqXLMOVPq3V4DEq-AJw/viewform?usp=sf_link), we can certainly help you out a bit better in there.

Comment: Solved. Thanks. Missing `Web Callback URLs` on https://connect.squareup.com/apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring this out of the comments, the issue was missing the web callback URL being registered in the [Square Developer Portal](https://connect.squareup.com/apps).

[You want to be sure to register your callback URL(s)](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android#specifywebcallbackuri)

> In order for Square Point of Sale to accept a request from your website, Square needs to verify that you have registered a web callback URI for the application in the Application Dashboard.
>
> First, go to the Application Dashboard, then click on the Point of Sale API tab of your application's settings. Under the Web section, specify your app's web callback URI under the corresponding field.

[If your transaction does not succeed for any reason, you should be receiving a error back to you.](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android#errorcodes)

Comment: In my case, this didn't fix it. I uninstalled Square Point Of Sale , and re-installed it, and it stopped crashing after.